# Counting views of any element on website

Tags: mysql, google-analytics, view

I am using such MySQL request for measuring views count

```
UPDATE content SET views=views+1 WHERE id='$id'
```

For example if I want to check how many times some single page has been viewed I've just putting it on top of page code. Unfortunately I always receiving about 5-10x bigger amount than results in Google Analytics.

If I am correct one refresh should increase value in my data base about +1. Doesn't "Views" in Google Analytics works in the same way?

If e.g. Google Analytics provides me that single page has been viewed 100x times and my data base says it was e.g. 450x times. How such simple request could generate additional 350 views? And I don't mean visits or unique visits. Just regular views.

Is it possible that Google Analytics interprates such data in a little bit different way and my data base result is correct?

Comment: I do not understand how the title relates to the question (the title asks about "any elements" in a website, which GA does not count separately, while the questions asks about pageviews). Can you elaborate a bit ?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few reasons why this could be occurring.  The most usual culprit is bots and spiders.   As soon as you use a third-party API like Google Analytics, or Facebook's API, you'll get their bots making hits to your page.

You need to examine each request in more detail.  The user agent is a good place to start, although I do recommend researching this area further - discriminating between human and bot traffic is quite a deep subject.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Analytics the data is provided by the user, for example:

A user view a page on your domain, now he is on charge to comunicate to Google The PageView, if something fails in the road, the data will no be included in the reports.

In the other case , the SQL sistem that you have is a Log Based Analytic, the data is collected by your system reducing the data collection failures.

If we see this in that way, that means taht some data can be missed with the slow conections and users that dont execute javascriopt (Adbloquers or bots), or the HTML page is not properly printed***.

Now 5x times more it's a huge discrepancy, in my experiences must be near 8-25% of discrepancy. (tested over transaction level, maybe in Pageview can be more)

What i recomend you is:
Save device, browser information, the ip, and some other metadata information that can be useful and dont forget the timesatmp, so in that way yo can isolate the problem, maybe are robots or users with adblock, in the worst case  you code is not properly implemented ( located in the Footer as example)

*** i added this because one time i had a huge discrepancy, but it was a server error, the HTML code was not properly printed showing to the user a empty HTTP. The MYSQL was no so fast to save the information and process the HTML code. I notice it when the effort test (via Screaming frog) showed a lot of 500x errors. ( Wordpress Blog with no cache)